# Using objective-c to create an HTTP POST message and handle returned XML data

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, http

**Introduction to the situation**

For an application I'm currently developing, I need to code up to a website's API to handle uploading of new videos, as well as validating user login and so forth. In the documentation for the API, the examples provided of how to use it is all in PHP, and I'm not sure what the best way of handling this is in objective-c, as when it comes to protocol programming my experience with the obj-c language falls short.

**Deeper explanation**

I shall avoid posting any details about the API as this should be kept secret, so I hope my explanation will be enough to generate a simple example/answer of some sort.

So the basic idea is that you send an HTTP POST request to the API url. The output of calling this URL will be XML information about the site and the current user logged in.

When sending the POST request to the API I have some choices about certain variables I want to send with the request, depending on what kind of information I want returned (This could be things like a user's password, user ID, and so forth).

The variables you send to the API is an array of alphabetically sorted key-value pairs (where the variable to send to the API is the key, and the value is what you want returned from that key).

**The Question**

My question simply is how you go about executing an HTTP POST request to a certain URL and handle returned XML data? Is there even any in-build functionality of doing so in obj-c?

I've been researching on this subject but I can't seem to find any information that's relevant to this specific problem, but if there is any articles on it then I would be grateful for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question simply is how you go about executing an HTTP POST request to a certain URL

You use `NSMutableURLRequest` for that. You can set the HTTP method, header fields, etc.

> and handle returned XML data?

`NSHTTPURLResponse` will provide the response data, whether it's in XML, JSON, HTML, whatever.

Another option is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is quite popular due to its ease of use.

Whatever you decide to use, start by reading the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) so that you have a solid understanding of the URL loading features built into the Foundation framework.

Comment: Note, that ASIHTTPRequest's development is discontinued: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thanks for pointing that out. I don't use it myself, so I hadn't noticed, but it's certainly been an incredibly popular tool. I hope that every one of the people who've built apps using it will buy a copy of the author's game.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Seems like this could be a possible approach, I will look into it. Thanks for the provided article too! Really appriciated.

Comment: I used it too, but now I am happy with AFNetworking, one of the tools mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

**To post data most people use ASIHTTPRequest:**

https://github.com/aidansteele/asi-http-request-1

Here's some sample code for a POST:

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@%@",[self getServer],url];        
ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setPostValue:json forKey:@"json"];
[request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

**Getting data back.**

I would strongly suggest using JSON with TouchJSON for iOS: 
https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

Once you get the reply from ASI you can simply run [replyString JSONValue] to get an array/dictionary representation for the JSON you encoded serverside.

Comment: Note, that ASIHTTPRequest's development is discontinued: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using ASIHTTPRequest. I've worked on projects that contained these classes in the past and personally I found it both slow and messy (i.e. ugly code). Perhaps it's improved nowadays, but there seems to be a much cleaner alternative.

Check out AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

A short introduction here: http://engineering.gowalla.com/2011/10/24/afnetworking/

This method might be interesting to you, makes dealing with XML responses very convenient: http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFXMLRequestOperation.html